# OpenCSV read two different file with different columns

Tags: java

I am stuck in a situation where I have to read from two different csv files and store them in single table.

CSV file1:

```
salary,date,user
121,2016-08-01,admin
121,2016-08-01,admin1
121,2016-08-01,admin2
121,2016-08-01,admin3
```

CSV file2:

```
salary,hour,user
322,11,admin4
477,4,admin5
78,5,admin6
```

What I am trying to do is read first row and differentiate between two csv files.

```
 CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
 String [] nextLine;
 while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) 
 {
   System.out.println(nextLine[1].contains("hour"));
   break;
 }
```

this is working, but want to know if there is any better way of doing this ?

Comment: Is It solved so far

Answer (score 1):

You are providing the filename as an input to read the file so you must be knowing that which file contains what. Instead of validating the header column name you can create this check on the basis of filename which you are providing to read file.